# Encountering some issues when enabling Role-based Support in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

A colleague deleted my instances thinking I had already made a backup (long story) and I'm in dire need of them to be restored as I would be losing an incredible amount of data.
Now, I'm trying to get support to see how they can help in the restoration.

So, I tried enabling Role-Based Support for my organisation in Google Cloud Platform, and one of the requirements is that I must be assigned The Support Account Administrator or Organisation Administrator role.

[image: role based support]

I thought I should have automatic access to everything as the owner of the account. However, I followed the instructions to assign the permission in the IAM & ADMIN page but I keep getting this error:
"You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page"

[image: error page]

How do I assign permissions if I am not allowed to even view the page? Mind you, I'm able to set permissions for my individual projects, but not the organisation.

Comment: You should follow the instruction from you first screenshot and ask your `Organization Administrator` provide you  `Support Account Administrator` accordingly  to make you able to use role-based support. For more details have a look at the documentation [Granting, changing, and revoking access to resources
](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access). Which roles do you have at the moment?

Comment: I am the owner and do not have an organization administrator. I should be able to assign myself whichever role I want, but that is not the case. I want to chat with support. Why does it have to be so hard?

Comment: Accordingly to the first screenshot you have the organization `aflon.org`. You should grant role to your account at the organization level by following the  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access). Do you have Owner role of the project or of the organization?

Answer (score 2):

I gone through this troubleshooting and finally able to add the standard support offerings by giving myself all these permissions.

Add the following roles to your user id

- cloud support admin permission

```
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding organizational_id --member='user:user_name@org.com' --role=roles/cloudsupport.admin
```

- organization admin permission

```
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding organizational_id --member='user:user_name@org.com' --role=roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin
```

- Billing admin

```
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding organizational_id --member='user:user_name@org.com' --role=roles/billing.admin
```

- Tech support editor needed for create/view support cases

```
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding organizational_id --member='user:user_name@org.com' --role=roles/cloudsupport.techSupportEditor
```

In addition to that you may need super admin permission.

Note: roles/owner is just the owner of the organization with access to all resources, this role does not give access to add standard support or view all IAM policies/roles

To find the organization ID

```
gcloud organizations list
```

Comment: The first command really works! Not sure why it is so  complicated.